# Why is np.arange(data.shape[1]+1)-.5 used to plot a heatmap?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I can't figure out what this piece of code does, because if I delete it, nothing changes in the **heatmap**, and I don't know what **"data.shape[1]+1)-.5"** and **".shape[]"** are doing in general

```
# Now enter the following code snippet to define the heatmap function
# map. First you need to prepare the chart:
def heatmap(data, row_labels, col_labels, ax=None, cbar_kw={},
        cbarlabel='',
        **kwargs):
    if not ax:
        ax = plt.gca()
    im = ax.imshow(data, **kwargs)

# Define the colorbar as a colorbar, as specified in the following code snippet:
    cbar = ax.figure.colorbar(im, ax=ax, **cbar_kw)
    cbar.ax.set_ylabel(cbarlabel, rotation=-90, va='bottom')

# Show all checkboxes and mark them with the corresponding entries in the list:
    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(data.shape[1]))
    ax.set_yticks(np.arange(data.shape[0]))
    ax.set_xticklabels(col_labels)
    ax.set_yticklabels(row_labels)

# Adjust the horizontal axes so that the marks appear on top of the graph:
    ax.tick_params(top=True, bottom=False, labeltop=True, labelbottom=False)

# Rotate the check marks and set their alignment:
    plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=-30, ha='right', rotation_mode='anchor')

# Turn off the frame and create a white grid for the graph, 
# as specified in the following code snippet:
    for edge, spine in ax.spines.items():
        spine.set_visible(False)
```

### I can't understand this piece of code

```
    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(data.shape[1]+1)-.5, minor=True)
    ax.set_yticks(np.arange(data.shape[0]+1)-.5, minor=True)
    ax.grid(which='minor', color='w', linestyle='-', linewidth=3)
    ax.tick_params(which='minor', bottom=False, left=False)
```

---

```
# Return the heat map:
    return im, cbar

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = np.array([
    [30, 20, 10],
    [10, 40, 15],
    [12, 10, 20],
])
im, cbar = heatmap(data, ['Class-1','Class-2','Class-3'], ['A','B','C'],
                   cmap='YlGn', cbarlabel='Number of Students')
plt.show()
```

Comment: That just changes the tick mark interval on the two axes.  It's possible the automatic tick mark stuff chose the same values you're setting there, so you don't see any change.

Comment: @TimRoberts And why does the value of 1 and 0 also have no effect on the changes in the graph? And what does -.5 mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data.shape` is the [numpy "shape"](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.shape.html) of the array. In this case, the data should be 2D. E.g. a 4x3 array has shape `(4,3)`.  As this is a tuple, you can write `data.shape[0]` to get the number of rows, which `sns.heatmap` uses in the y-direction. And `data.shape[1]` for the number of columns.

In the case of a square array, as in the post's example, the number of rows and columns is equal, so there seems to be no change if you interchange them. But, be ready for a surprise when you test the same code with a non-square array.

`np.arange(data.shape[1])` would be `np.arange(3)`, or just the numbers `[0,1,2]`.  These are the positions of the centers of the heatmap cells. They are often used to label a column of the cells. If you'd use seaborn's [`sns.heatmap()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) these major ticks would be placed automatically.

`np.arange(data.shape[1] + 1) - .5` gives `np.array([0,1,2,3] - 0.5)` (note how Python allows leaving out the zero in decimal numbers). Thanks to numpy's [vectorization](https://unidata.github.io/python-training/workshop/NumPy/numpy-broadcasting-and-vectorization/) (and broadcasting), this becomes `[-0.5,0.5,1.5,2.5]`. These are the positions of the boundaries of the cells (one boundary more than there are cells).  You can use to position the minor ticks, and draw some fancy borders.  With `ax.grid(which='minor', color='w', linestyle='-', linewidth=3)` the cells are surrounded by a white line (thickness 3, standard linestyle, using the position of the minor ticks). If you left it out, there wouldn't be any separation between the cells.

Here is how seaborn would create a similar heatmap:

```py
import seaborn as sns

data = [[30, 20, 10],
        [10, 40, 15],
        [12, 10, 20]]
ax = sns.heatmap(data, xticklabels=['Class-1', 'Class-2', 'Class-3'], yticklabels=['A', 'B', 'C'],
                 cmap='YlGn', cbar=True, cbar_kws={'label': 'Number of Students'},
                 linewidths=3, linecolor='white',
                 annot=True)
```

Note how seaborn created annotations, with the color (white or black) depending on the cell's darkness.

[image: sns.heatmap]

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comprehensive response. This help me move on to the next step!